# Zeroth component of 4-momentum and relativistic energy-momentum relation

Tags: special-relativity, energy, spacetime, momentum, vectors

As I understand it one is forced to use 4-vectors since we require objects that transform as vectors under application of Lorentz transformations and 3-vectors do not (technically they do under rotations, but not under boosts). Equivalenty, if one starts off with Minkowski spacetime from the outset, then 4-vectors are the natural quantities to consider since we are already dealing with a 4-dimensional space.

Given this, one then introduces the notion of 4-momentum, defining it as $$p^{\mu}=m\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}=\gamma m\frac{dx^{\mu}}{dt}$$ where $x^{\mu}$ is the position 4-vector, $\tau$ is the proper time, $t$ is the coordinate time and $\gamma =\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}}$ is the Lorentz factor (with $\mathbf{v}$ the relative velocity between two inertial frames).

I'm trying to reason why the zeroth component of 4-momentum of a particle, i.e. $p^{0}$ is proportional to its energy $E$, $$p^{0}=\frac{E}{c}$$ where $c$ is the speed of light.

Can one do this as follows.
We first note that, by definition, $p^{0}=\gamma mc=\frac{mc}{\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}}$, and so for $v<<c$ we have that $$ p^{0}=\gamma mc=\frac{mc}{\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}}\approx mc(1+\frac{v^{2}}{2c^{2}})=\frac{1}{c}(mc^{2}+\frac{mv^{2}}{2})$$ We recognise $ \frac{mv^{2}}{2}$ as the kinetic energy of a non-relativistic particle and hence interpret $mc^{2}+\frac{mv^{2}}{2}$ as the total energy of the particle in the non-relativistic limit. Thus we are motivated to interpret $p^{0}$ as being proportional to the energy of the particle, i.e. $p^{0}=\frac{E}{c}$.

Given this we can then proceed to derive the relativistic energy-momentum relation: $$ (p^{0})^{2}=\frac{E^{2}}{c^{2}}=\gamma^{2}m^{2}c^{2}= \frac{m^{2}c^{2}}{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}= \frac{m^{2}c^{2}+m^{2}v^{2}-m^{2}v^{2}}{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}\\ =\frac{m^{2}v^{2}}{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}+m^{2}\frac{c^{2}-v^{2}}{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}=p^{2}+m^{2}c^{2}$$ and hence $$E^{2}=m^{2}c^{4}+p^{2}c^{2}.$$

Have I understood this concept correctly? Is the derivation correct? I'd really appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Energy is the integral of motion associated with time translation invariance. Spatial momentum is associated with 3d space translation invariance (and so is a 3d vector). One combines these quantities into the integral of motion associated with space-time translations (and thus this integral is a 4d vector). Naturally, 0th component of 4-momentum is associated with time translations and thus is essentially energy, up to a constant factor, which can be determined by your analysis.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Ah OK, thanks for the info. Would what I put in my post be a correct way of deducing it at all though?

Comment: Well, what your post shows is that, given the formula $p^\mu=dx^\mu/d\tau$, its 0th component reduces to kinetic energy in the non-relativistic limit, plus a constant. But there are many quantities which will reduce to kinetic energy in non-relativistic limit, and only one of them is the actual energy. Your reasoning doesn't show why 0th component of $p^\mu$ is special enough to be called energy, and it also hinges on the specific formula. The things I said in my comment above hold regardless of what system you are studying, and you will perhaps appreciate it when and if you get to study QFT.

Comment: If you add to your post that $p^\mu$ is _conserved_, then it will be closer to the truth, and if you furthermore note what symmetry this conservation is associated with, you will essentially have the argument in my comment.

Comment: (To clarify, you cannot _deduce_ what I said, since energy is basically by the very definition the integral of motion associated with time translation symmetry. You can use other definitions, but this one is the most universal and useful, at least in flat space. And if you need to see how the time translation is related to energy, look for Noether's theorem)

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Can one use Noether's theorem from classical non-relativistic mechanics to argue why four-momentum is natural constructed from a quantity that is associated with spatial translation invariance and a quantity that is associated with time translation invariance, such that the resulting four-vector is conserved under tanslations in spacetime?

Comment: Noether's theorem doesn't care about the nature of your system, so it is the same for relativistic and non-relativistic setting. But yes, if you take a Lagrangian (assumed to be Lorentz-invariant), and write energy and 3-momentum for it using Noether's theorem, you will find that you can naturally combine these into a covariant (or contravariant) 4-vector, which will coincide with the vector you get from spacetime translations. (This is basically the statement that you can combine $\partial/\partial x_0$ and $\partial/\partial x_i,\, i=1,2,3$ into a 4-vector if these act on a Lorentz scalar).